# Open video file by "Movies & TV" (windows 10)

Tags: c#, winforms, win-universal-app

Using `Process.Start(@"C:\clip.mp4")` will open video with default apps.

How can I open it with app "Movies & TV" (it's not default app) in C# Windows Form?

Comment: You can launch the app by `mswindowsvideo:` protocol but I don't think there is a way to specify the video file to open.

Comment: The "Movies and TV" should take a file path as a parameter or the jump list and open-with would not work when it is not the default app. I am trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 1):

Necroposting here. I have had found out that you could treat the `mswindowsvideo://` protocol as an application path on the command line.

Simply write on a command line or shell:

```
start "mswindowsvideo://" "<filePath>"
```

**In your code**, that would be: `Process.Start("mswindowsvideo://", filePath);`

Comment: this not working on windows 11, it's opening the file in the default program when ran from powershell (VLC in my case), and opening the Videos app without loading the file when ran from cmd

Comment: @SDIDSA I won't upgrade to Windows 10, but I can infer that Windows 11 modifies registry keys stored at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\mswindowsvideo or HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mswindowsvideo. 

I suggest checking them, since this method was working at an early version of Windows 11--based on [this article](https://winaero.com/windows-11-uri-commands-to-launch-apps-directly/#:~:text=November%2015,%202021) when I was finding a URI scheme for Windows apps.

Answer (score -1):

For UWP you can use [`Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher).

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile); //in my case this is .mkv file
```